# Kicking upon command

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to execute this command and have it kick them in the end but it just reacts and sends them the embed, anyone know how to fix this?

```
#Command to send a user their termination letter
@bot.command()
async def terminate(ctx, user : discord.User, *, reason = "No reason provided."):
    reason = "".join(reason)
    date = datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    embed = Embed(title="Terminated",
                  description=f"Hello *{user.display_name}*, as of `{date}`, at `{time} GMT`, you're being **TERMINATED** from *__California Department of Public Safety__* by {ctx.author.name} for `{reason}`, this decision was made by myself and the DPS Command Staff and seen best fit. If you have any questions or concerns feel free to contact me, otherwise have a nice day/night.",
                  color=0xe74c3c)
  
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Action By {ctx.author.name} | {ctx.guild.name}', icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/935059565588930601/945768014958178324/ezgif-1-5c3f7a6a54.gif?width=778&height=778")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(f'✅')
    await user.send(embed=embed)
    await user.kick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the `discord.User` object.

`discord.User` and `discord.Member` has differences, although most of it's methods/attributes are the same.

So the main thing is, that `discord.User` does not have the `kick()` method.

You should use `discord.Member` for moderation actions, as `discord.User` has no methods for moderation actions.

The proper code should be something like this:

```py
#Command to send a user their termination letter
@bot.command()
async def terminate(ctx, user : discord.Member, *, reason = "No reason provided."):
    reason = "".join(reason)
    date = datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    embed = Embed(title="Terminated",
                  description=f"Hello *{user.display_name}*, as of `{date}`, at `{time} GMT`, you're being **TERMINATED** from *__California Department of Public Safety__* by {ctx.author.name} for `{reason}`, this decision was made by myself and the DPS Command Staff and seen best fit. If you have any questions or concerns feel free to contact me, otherwise have a nice day/night.",
                  color=0xe74c3c)
  
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Action By {ctx.author.name} | {ctx.guild.name}', icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/935059565588930601/945768014958178324/ezgif-1-5c3f7a6a54.gif?width=778&height=778")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(f'✅')
    await user.send(embed=embed)
    await user.kick()
```

## References

[API Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)

[discord.User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User)

[discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member)

If this answer is unclear, let me know!